# how to primary key auto increment id use in different column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

my question is i create menu master table in that table i m mention menu_id is primary key auto increment also and in same table i create set_rank column the issue is when i insert menu update menu_id and set_rank both field id will be same
    and use $set_rank_id=mysql_insert_id(); but when i enter new entry it show to entry...

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO menu_master SET
            hotel_id        = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['hotel_id'])."',
            menu_name       = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['menu_name'])."',
            menu_name_ar    = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['menu_name_ar'])."',
            is_active       = '".$is_active."'";
            //echo $sql."<br/>";

                mysql_query($sql);

                $set_rank_id=mysql_insert_id();




                   $sql = "INSERT INTO menu_master SET
            set_rank = '".$set_rank_id."'";

                mysql_query($sql);
            $sql_sitelog = "UPDATE ".SITELOG." SET 
            site_updated_on='".date('Y-m-d G:i:s a')."'";
            mysql_query($sql_sitelog);
```

Comment: Of course, because you are `INSERT`ing two rows. If you want to **update** an existing row, do an `UPDATE` query. Is this really useful to have two redundant columns though? Will you change the value of `set_rank` later?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Once you have obtained the last insert id using

```
$set_rank_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

You should set this value in set_rank  field only for that particular record 
so you could use the following query

```
$sql = "update menu_master set set_rank = $set_rank_id where menu_id = $set_rank_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO menu_master SET
            set_rank = '".$set_rank_id."'";
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE menu_master SET
            set_rank = '".$set_rank_id."'" WHERE menu_id='".$set_rank_id."'";
```